# Calculate conditional average on disjoint cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I would like to know if libreoffice calc has the functionality to calculate an conditional average on disjoint cells. An example would be: Calculate the average for every second cell in Row1 if Row2 does not contain an x.

```
     | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 | C8 | C9
--------------------------------------------------
Row1 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9
Row2 |  x |  x |    |    |    |  x |  x |    |
```

Beginning at C1 the result should be: mean(3, 5, 9) = 5.666666
Beginning at C2 the result should be: mean(4, 8) = 6

Although there is a solution using IF statements for every cell I would like to know if there is a more convinient way to do it. I already searched for a solution like LOOKUP or COUNTIF but all those functions need a consecutive range as input for the data and condition.

I hope someone can help.

**[EDIT]:** Answer

I finally found a solution by myself. The asnwer is to use the `SUMPRODUCT` function in addition to another row or the `MOD` function:

`=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(COLUMN(C1:C9), 2)=0, C1Row2:C9Row2<>"x", C1Row1:C9Row1)/SUMPRODUCT(MOD(COLUMN(C1:C9), 2)=0, C1Row2:C9Row2<>"x")`

Comment: Excel has a function named 'AVERAGEIF' that can conditionally compute the mean if conditions are met. Not sure if calc has the same thing.

Comment: I found the DAVERAGE function but I can't get it to work properly and the problem with the disjoint cells remains...

Comment: DAVERAGE is probably not what you want. I think you either need to look at writing a macro, reorganizing your data to be together or writing the formulas manually (ie (C3 + C5 + C9) / 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution by myself. The asnwer is to use the SUMPRODUCT function in addition to another row or the MOD function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(COLUMN(C1:C9), 2)=0, C1Row2:C9Row2<>"x", C1Row1:C9Row1)/SUMPRODUCT(MOD(COLUMN(C1:C9), 2)=0, C1Row2:C9Row2<>"x")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have immediate access to LibreOffice Calc. 
You can do this in Microsoft Excel by using the `AVERAGEIFS` function and a “helper row”. 
I’ve chosen Row 42.  In cell `A42`, enter `=MOD(COLUMN(), 2)`, then drag/fill that out to `I42`
(i.e., far enough to correspond to all your data; in your example, you show nine columns). 
This should give you an alternating sequence of `1`, `0`, `1`, `0`, … 
Then the answer that you want is

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:I1, A2:I2, "<>x", A42:I42, 1)
```

i.e., the average of the values within `A1:I1` for which the value in Row 2 is not “x”
and the value in Row 42 is 1.

You said “if Row2 does not contain an x”.  I interpreted that to mean “if the corresponding value
in Row 2 is not `x`”.  If you mean “if the corresponding value in Row 2 does not *contain* an `x`”
(so words like “excel” and “fox” would also invalidate the corresponding value in Row 1),
you’ll probably need a second “helper row” to handle that.